# Start and stop sounds in Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java), I would like to play a WAV file in a Java application - however, I would also like the ability to pause, resume, and restart the sound. I'm guessing I can restart by pausing and then just creating a new sound, but how would I pause and resume in the first place?

Note that my sound is ~15minutes and 152.8mb. If there is a way to do this with an MP3 file (same length, 20.8mb) that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playing WAV files, see the answers to this question:
[Problem with Javas Audio Clips on frequent playback of beep sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627730/problem-with-javas-audio-clips-on-frequent-playback-of-beep-sounds)

For playing MP3s, you can use [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html) which is a fairly small jar (100k I think, maybe smaller) that you can bundle with your application.

Here's a fairly decent example of how to use it:
[MP3.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/mp3/MP3.java.html) (from [How to play an MP3 file in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/mp3/mp3.html))

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac -classpath .:jl1.0.jar MP3.java         (OS X)
 *                javac -classpath .;jl1.0.jar MP3.java         (Windows)
 *  Execution:    java -classpath .:jl1.0.jar MP3 filename.mp3  (OS X / Linux)
 *                java -classpath .;jl1.0.jar MP3 filename.mp3  (Windows)
 *  
 *  Plays an MP3 file using the JLayer MP3 library.
 *
 *  Reference:  http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html
 *
 *
 *  To execute, get the file jl1.0.jar from the website above or from
 *
 *      http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/24inout/jl1.0.jar
 *
 *  and put it in your working directory with this file MP3.java.
 *
 *************************************************************************/

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class MP3 {
    private String filename;
    private Player player; 

    // constructor that takes the name of an MP3 file
    public MP3(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void close() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

    // play the MP3 file to the sound card
    public void play() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            player = new Player(bis);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // run in new thread to play in background
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try { player.play(); }
                catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
        }.start();

    }


    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = args[0];
        MP3 mp3 = new MP3(filename);
        mp3.play();

        // do whatever computation you like, while music plays
        int N = 4000;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                sum += Math.sin(i + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

        // when the computation is done, stop playing it
        mp3.close();

        // play from the beginning
        mp3 = new MP3(filename);
        mp3.play();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Similar to this question, I would like to play a WAV file in a Java application - however, I would also like the ability to pause, resume, and restart the sound. I'm guessing I can restart by pausing and then just creating a new sound, but how would I pause and resume in the first place?

The `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` would be ideal for this, *except* for the fact that most implementations of `Clip` will not load more than 2 seconds of stereo, 16 bit, 44.1KHz sound!  For that reason I developed [BigClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-audio-file-in-java-application/5668510#5668510).  `BigClip` can handle sounds that are as big as the available memory.

> Note that my sound is ~15minutes and 152.8mb. If there is a way to do this with an MP3 file (same length, 20.8mb) that would be even better.

Sure thing.  As mentioned in the [JavaSound tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)..

> ### MP3 decoding support
>
> The Java Sound API does not support many formats of sampled sound internally. In a 1.6.0_24 Oracle JRE getAudioFileTypes() will generally return {WAVE, AU, AIFF}. An MP3 decoder at least, is close by. The mp3plugin.jar of the Java Media Framework supports decoding MP3s.

I currently use `BigClip` & the mp3plugin.jar Jar in the DukeBox player.  Given 1024Meg of memory, it can easily load both the 17:12 of the *1812 Overture*, & 15:38 of *Bolero* (the two longest tracks in my favorites play list).  I mention 'both' since it will load the next track while playing the current one.

---

As an aside, beware of looking at code that mentions the `sun.audio` packages (mentioned in both linked threads).  This package and/or it's classes might be moved or removed in the next release (at Oracle's discretion) & have not been necessary  since **Java 1.3.**