# Java Clip (sound) 'echoing' and not playing efficiantly

Tags: java, audio, clip

SOLVED

There was a problem with Runnable, so there were acually TWO game threads running at the same time. (Equals problem!) So the second thread that hit the audio player made the error, and thats why it sounded echoy- it was playing from two different threads!

I also am using SourceDataLine, as suggested, to enable longer sound clips.

Original post-

---

When this code fires, an error pops up saying

`IllegalStateException: Mixer is already open`

at the `clip.open()` line. I have put in every measure to check if the code is being ran twice, it is not. However, even with the error, the sound still plays. On longer clips (30 seconds) it sounds like theres 2 sounds playing, one right after the other. On REALLY long clips (3 minutes) the sound stutters.

(`stringFile` is a `String`, such as `"example.wav"`)

```
File soundFile = new File(stringFile);
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start();
playing = true;
```

If this question was already posted, I am very sorry. I have searched and I found no thread similar to this one.

Comment: You might have more luck using [BigClip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-audio-file-in-java-application/5668510#5668510).  BTW - what OS & Java are you running?  The non-Sun *nix JRE allowed arbitrarily sized `Clip` instances (and the implementation was generally buggy), but Sun/Oracle's `Clip` is very limited in the length of sound it can load.

Comment: Thanks. Im using linux mint, and openjdk or sun java, not sure what Eclipse is using :p Ill try BigClip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking, but part of the point of using a Clip is that you can keep the Clip in memory and call it multiple times, without having to reload it from a file.

Thus, to start and stop, you would use myClip.open(), myClip.start(), myClip.stop(), and to play it again, myClip.setFramePosition(0) and myClip.start() if I read the Tutorial correctly. (I just work with SourceDataLines, usually, so forgive me if I have this wrong.)

If you are reloading it from a file every time, could that cause or contribute to the problem? In any case, I'd consider switching to a SourceDataLine. Among other things, this eliminates the overhead of having to load the entire clip into memory before it can start playing.

30 seconds is a lot of RAM, by the way. 30 * 44100 = 1.323 MB (and that's with just 1 byte per frame, a more common wav format is 4 times that size). Thus, with your longer sounds you might be taxing your RAM to the point of page swapping which would cause stuttering.

Comment: The code I posted is the initial load, not the replay. I tried looking into SourceDataLine, but it seems so complex- fiddling with the actual bytes of the sound file and feeding them manually into the player. I do not know where to start! Everything I've tried with it failed.

Comment: nevermind, after some intense studying at 2:30 am i got it to work!

Comment: @khyperia -- Congrats! Yes, getting the SDL to work for the first time was hard for me as well. But once you have it, it gives you so much more control of the process. Having access to the inner byte buffer feed: I've started doing volume controlling and playback rate controlling at the per frame level, and am looking at getting into some simple filtering and other effects.