# How to load media resources from the classpath in JMF

Tags: java, jar, jmf

I have a Java application that I want to turn into an executable jar. I am using JMF in this application, and I can't seem to get the sound files working right...

I create the jar using

```
jar cvfm jarname.jar manifest.txt *.class *.gif *.wav
```

So, all the sound files get put inside the jar, and in the code, I am creating the Players using

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(ClassName.class.getResource("song1.wav"));
```

The jar is on my desktop, and when I attempt to run it, this exception occurs:

```
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :jar:file:/C:/Users/Pojo/
Desktop/jarname.jar!/song1.wav
```

...It's not getting IOExceptions, so it seems to at least be finding the file itself all right.

Also, before I used the getResource, I used to have it like this:

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new File("song1.wav").toURL());
```

and it was playing fine, so I know nothing is wrong with the sound file itself.

The reason I am trying to switch to this method instead of the File method is so that the sound files can be packaged inside the jar itself and not have to be its siblings in a directory.

Comment: Why use JMF for sound?  the `javax.sound.sampled` API has been part of the J2SE since 1.3.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
Is there anything else in `javax.sound.sampled` besides Clip? Because I've tried using Clip and it just wouldn't work for these files because they're too big and Clip refuses to play anything bigger than about 1MB

Comment: *"Clip refuses to play anything bigger than about 1MB"*  A) You probably should be looking to convert those to MP3 format, so they'll (generally) be smaller than the WAV. B) If you do that, then the `mp3plugin.jar` of the JMF will be needed to decode the MP3, but not the entire JMF. C) Oracle's implementation of `Clip` can handle at most 1 second of 44.1 KHz 16 bit stereo, but there are two other ways to handle large audio. 1) [BigClip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-audio-file-in-java-application/5668510#5668510) 2) Load the stream and play it chunk by chunk.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
Weeeell... It's a relatively large wav file that needs to loop. For this, I settled on jmf as my solution. And it all works, just for some reason not... while inside a jar. Besides, you said BigClip has issues with looping, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New solution:

First, a custom `DataSource` class that returns a `SourceStream` that implements `Seekable` is needed:

```
package com.ziesemer.test;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import javax.media.Duration;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Time;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.PullDataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.PullSourceStream;
import javax.media.protocol.Seekable;

/**
 * @author Mark A. Ziesemer
 *  <a href="http://www.ziesemer.com.">&lt;www.ziesemer.com&gt;</a>
 */
public class JarDataSource extends PullDataSource{

    protected JarURLConnection conn;
    protected ContentDescriptor contentType;
    protected JarPullSourceStream[] sources;
    protected boolean connected;

    public JarDataSource(URL url) throws IOException{
        setLocator(new MediaLocator(url));
        connected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public PullSourceStream[] getStreams(){
        return sources;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException{
        conn = (JarURLConnection)getLocator().getURL().openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        connected = true;

        JarFile jf = conn.getJarFile();
        JarEntry je = jf.getJarEntry(conn.getEntryName());

        String mimeType = conn.getContentType();
        if(mimeType == null){
            mimeType = ContentDescriptor.CONTENT_UNKNOWN;
        }
        contentType = new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.mimeTypeToPackageName(mimeType));

        sources = new JarPullSourceStream[1];
        sources[0] = new JarPullSourceStream(jf, je, contentType);
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType(){
        return contentType.getContentType();
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect(){
        if(connected){
            try{
                sources[0].close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connected = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws IOException{
        // Nothing to do.
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws IOException{
        // Nothing to do.
    }

    @Override
    public Time getDuration(){
        return Duration.DURATION_UNKNOWN;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getControls(){
        return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getControl(String controlName){
        return null;
    }

    protected class JarPullSourceStream implements PullSourceStream, Seekable, Closeable{

        protected final JarFile jarFile;
        protected final JarEntry jarEntry;
        protected final ContentDescriptor type;

        protected InputStream stream;
        protected long position;

        public JarPullSourceStream(JarFile jarFile, JarEntry jarEntry, ContentDescriptor type) throws IOException{
            this.jarFile = jarFile;
            this.jarEntry = jarEntry;
            this.type = type;
            this.stream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
        }

        @Override
        public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor(){
            return type;
        }

        @Override
        public long getContentLength(){
            return jarEntry.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean endOfStream(){
            return position < getContentLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getControls(){
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getControl(String controlType){
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willReadBlock(){
            if(endOfStream()){
                return true;
            }
            try{
                return stream.available() == 0;
            }catch(IOException e){
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException{
            int read = stream.read(buffer, offset, length);
            position += read;
            return read;
        }

        @Override
        public long seek(long where){
            try{
                if(where < position){
                    stream.close();
                    stream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
                    position = 0;
                }
                long skip = where - position;
                while(skip > 0){
                    long skipped = stream.skip(skip);
                    skip -= skipped;
                    position += skipped;
                }
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                // Made a best effort.
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long tell(){
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRandomAccess(){
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException{
            try{
                stream.close();
            }finally{
                jarFile.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Then, the above custom data source is used to create a player, and a `ControllerListener` is added to cause the player to loop:

```
package com.ziesemer.test;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.Time;

/**
 * @author Mark A. Ziesemer
 *  <a href="http://www.ziesemer.com.">&lt;www.ziesemer.com&gt;</a>
 */
public class JmfTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        URL url = JmfTest.class.getResource("Test.wav");
        JarDataSource jds = new JarDataSource(url);
        jds.connect();
        final Player player = Manager.createPlayer(jds);

        player.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener(){
            @Override
            public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce){
                if(ce instanceof EndOfMediaEvent){
                    player.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
                    player.start();
                }
            }
        });
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Note that without the custom data source, JMF tries repeatedly to seek back to the beginning - but fails, and eventually gives up.  This can be seen from debugging the same `ControllerListener`, which will receive a several events for each attempt.

Or, using the `MediaPlayer` approach to loop (that you mentioned on my previous answer):

```
package com.ziesemer.test;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.bean.playerbean.MediaPlayer;

/**
 * @author Mark A. Ziesemer
 *  <a href="http://www.ziesemer.com.">&lt;www.ziesemer.com&gt;</a>
 */
public class JmfTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        URL url = JmfTest.class.getResource("Test.wav");
        JarDataSource jds = new JarDataSource(url);
        jds.connect();
        final Player player = Manager.createPlayer(jds);

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setPlayer(player);
        mp.setPlaybackLoop(true);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Again, I would not consider this production-ready code (could use some more Javadocs and logging, etc.), but it is tested and working (Java 1.6), and should meet your needs nicely.

Merry Christmas, and happy holidays!

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Z! You came through for me once again! (This time for real) ^_^

Comment: @ziesemer It araised an exception                          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection
 at com.JarDataSource.connect(JarDataSource.java:39)
 at com.JmfTest.main(JmfTest.java:20)

Comment: @Srivathsan - Are you using the code as-provided, or with modifications?  What JDK version?

Comment: @ziesemer I'm using the same code as you described above. My JDK version is 6.

Answer (score 3):

This is a far cry from production code, but this seems resolved any runtime exceptions (though it's not actually wired up to play anything yet):

```
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.protocol.URLDataSource;

// ...

URL url = JmfTest.class.getResource("song1.wav");
System.out.println("url: " + url);
URLDataSource uds = new URLDataSource(url);
uds.connect();
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(uds);
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you once again Mr. ziesemer. You have saved my project. I salute you. <3

Comment: Wait, hold on. It turns out that the sound files don't loop anymore, even by explicitly calling setPlaybackLoop(true) on the MediaPlayer. They play through once, and then are never heard from again. They should loop forever...

Comment: Please include your additional code that actual plays and loops the sound, so that we have something to work against.

Comment: Well, I'm creating the Players exactly like you did in this answer; create the URLDataSource object, then call .connect() on it, then assign it to a new player with Manager.createPlayer(URLDataSourceobject). 

Then, I do `MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); player.setPlaybackLoop(true);`

Comment: ...Then, of course, I'm doing `player.setPlayer(thePlayerObjectCreatedByTheManager); player.start();`

Basically, before I implemented your getResource stuff, I was just getting the URLs from `File`s, and it looped fine. Now, I modified the `Player` creation code to use `getResource` and now it doesn't loop anymore. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
Manager.createPlayer(this.getClass().getResource("/song1.wav"));
```

That will work if the `song1.wav` is in the root of a Jar that is on the run-time class-path of the application.

Comment: does it have to be `this.getClass()`? Can I not just use the class name .class ?

Comment: You could have tried that quicker than adding a comment and waiting for me to ask *"What happened when you tried it?"*.

Comment: Tsk. Silly smart people these days... Well, I tried both. Neither worked.