# Media: Play WAV file inside JAR

Tags: java, javafx-2

There is only one constructor of the `Media`-class: `public Media(java.lang.String source)` see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29

This constructor gets a URI as string. I have a JavaFX project and put a WAV file inside this project. When I deploy the project as a JAR, I can see (with 7-Zip for example), that the WAV file is also exported. There is no problem to get the content with

```
MyApplicationClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/test.wav").
```

But what is the correct URI to refer this WAV file inside the deployed JAR for the `Media` constructor? The URI

```
new Media("jar:.!/resources/test.wav")
```

doesnt work. The URI `"jar:resources/test.wav"` fails too (becouse there is no reference to the JAR file).

Does anybody have an idea about the correct URI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one out

```
new Media(MyApplicationClass.class.getResource("/resources/test.wav").toURI().toString())
```

Media accepts jar uris so it should work fine

Comment: Thank you! `ViMu.class.getResource("/audio/click_track_a.wav").toURI().toString()` gives a correct URI `jar:file:/C:Users/oliver/Desktop/vimu.jar!audio/click_track_a.wav` and the `Media` object created correctly becouse there is no `MEDIA UNAVAILABLE`. But by playing it with `MediaPlayer` I can't here it. With the URI `file:/D:/Workspace/vimu/bin/audio/click_track_a.wav` I can here it.

Comment: this is using JMF:

URL url = ViMu.class.getResource("/audio/click_track_a.wav");
URLDataSource uds = new URLDataSource(url);
uds.connect();
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(uds);

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304940/how-to-load-media-resources-from-the-classpath-in-jmf

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will consider JMF for it and hope, that JavaFX `Media` will accept arbitary `InputStream`s in the future.

Comment: Ahh, the problem is the length of the WAV file. I've tested with 1 s WAV and it works. MediaPlayer is very buggy :)

Comment: this does not work for valid MP4 video resources (using 1.8.0_51). ~25s video will play once and then freeze. when i copy the jar URL to a temporary file and use that as the source, it will loop. @Vertex yes, JavaFX is very buggy in general.