# JavaFX Media-Loop

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, media-player

I have the following code, which creates a `MediaPlayer` and plays an audio:

```
public void playSong(Songs song) {
    this.media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/sounds/login_song.wav").toString());
    this.soundPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    this.soundPlayer.setVolume(this.currentVolume);
    this.soundPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    this.soundPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    this.soundPlayer.play();
}
```

for creating an audio-loop I used:

```
this.soundPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
this.soundPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
```

This works, when Iam starting my application from IDE. Iam using: Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

When I export my application to a runnable JAR-file, the audio is only played once and doesnt loop. Running the Jar from terminal does not help, since no errors occur (java -jar MyApplication.jar).

Why are the audios not looping?

Comment: could you run this command in CMD `java -jar JARNAME.jar`

Comment: Hello, I said "running the jar from terminal does not help, since no errors occur". I used your command.

Comment: sorry didn't see

Comment: you can make some tests to know where exactly is the problem you can change the file , try on a different machine , use another IDE or try different file extension. 
I had a problem before with mp4 files changing some video attribute such as bit rate and frame rate made the video to work

Comment: You might be running into the same issue noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818209/javafx-mediaplayer-mp4-wont-loop-on-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment88583553_46818209

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code and it worked well from both IDE and jar, but i have a hack for you if you want to loop indefinitely using the setOnEndOfMedia() method like this

UPDATE:

not a perfect solution but recreating the media player in onEndOfMedia will somehow solve this problem (i did this try catch block to get visual exceptions while testing from the jar)

```
MediaPlayer mp;
Media m = null;

@Override
public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
    try {
        m = new Media(getClass().getResource("/play.wav").toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
        Runnable onEnd = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp.dispose();
                mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
                mp.play();
                mp.setOnEndOfMedia(this);
            }
        };
        mp.setOnEndOfMedia(onEnd);
        mp.play();
        ps.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Alert al = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        al.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
        al.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: My first approach actually was using EndOfMedia, but this didnt work either. Thats why I switched to setAutoPlay.

Comment: i tried the code above from jar and that's right it only loops three times (i'm using a very short media) and then stops without throwing any exception, i will keep looking into this and let you know when i find anything

Comment: Thats weird. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: are you trying it from the IDE or from a built jar? If IDE, are you using eclipse as well?

Comment: there is no problem with looping when i run from IDE, the problem is present when running from jar !

Comment: But with which IDE did you build the jar?

Comment: eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)