# Java/Eclipse won't play sound

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

**Figured it out and answered the question myself**
I have this code and I am pretty sure this is supposed to make a sound but it won't. The program shows no errors when it runs but won't produce sound.
I need help figuring out why it is not working.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;

  if(true)
  {
     File file= new File("GodzillaWAV.wav");
     AudioClip roar= Applet.newAudioClip(file);
     roar.loop();
  }
```

Thanks to those that could help.

Comment: Have you tried using `roar.play();`?

Comment: This code cannot be real. There is no AudioClip class in Java with a method named 'roar'. And you have no variable named 'quack'.

Comment: Sorry it is supposed to say roar.loop(); Originially it is supposed to be quack.loop(); but I cliked on loop and edited that instead of quack.

Comment: Please show us some ***real*** code.

Comment: What do you mean this is **real** code.

Comment: What the hell why am i getting negative votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works no clue why or why not but it works.

```
  if(true)
  {
     File file = new File("GodzillaWAV.wav");
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     AudioInputStream Audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
     clip.open(Audio);
     clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
     Thread.sleep(6000);
  }
```

Comment: It's because it's a .wav file, not a .mp3 file like you were trying to play. The JMF contains tools that actually support .mp3 files. You might consider looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't play mp3 files using `AudioClip`, unfortunately. You can either try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293129/3386144) answer or download the file and convert it to wave sound (.wav).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
String MainSound =  "/Users/al/DevDaily/Projects/MeditationApp/resources/gong.au";
InputStream inSound = new FileInputStream(MainSound);
AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inSound );
AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
```

Comment: Instead of a url I am using a file and using this code it only plays for a fraction second then cuts out

Comment: Okay so you are using a File now? Okay then it will be easier than before, To play it you from A file you should do that: