# Losing control of my application while reading an audio file

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a Java application, with 2 buttons : Start and Stop.

When I click on the Start button, I read an audio file. But there is a problem. When I read the music, it is impossible to click on the other button. I lost the control of my application until the entire audio file is read. So I can't stop the reading by clicking my button.

I think I have to use a thread, but I have some difficulties to understand how thread are working.

Can you help me please ?

**Here is my ServerBoard :**

```
public class ServerBoard extends JFrame
{
    private TCPServer tcpserver;
    private Sound sound;
    private JTextArea messagearea;
    private JButton startserver;
    private JButton playmusic;
    private JButton stopmusic;


    /** CONSTRUCTEUR **/
    public ServerBoard(int l, int h)
    {
        ...
    }

    /** Initialisation de la fenetre **/
    public void initialize()
            {
        ...
    }


/**********************************************************************************************
 ************************************** ADD PANELS **************************************
 **********************************************************************************************/
    private JPanel createPanelEast()
    {
        ...

        return panelEast;
    }


/**********************************************************************************************
 ************************************* ADD LISTENERS ************************************
 **********************************************************************************************/
    private class ServerBoardListener implements ActionListener
    {    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String namebutton=e.getActionCommand().trim();

            if(namebutton.equals("START SERVER"))
            {
                startServer();
            }

            else if(namebutton.equals("PLAY MUSIC"))
            {
                playMusic();
            }

            else if(namebutton.equals("STOP MUSIC"))
            {
                stopMusic();
            }
        }
    }


/**********************************************************************************************
 ****************************************** METHODS ******************************************
 **********************************************************************************************/
    // METHODE POUR DEMARRER LE SERVEUR
    public void startServer()
    {
        // Une fois clique, on desactive le bouton
        startserver.setEnabled(false);

        // On cree l'objet OnMessageReceved demande par le constructeur de TCPServer
        tcpserver=new TCPServer(new TCPServer.OnMessageReceived()
                    {
            public void messageReceived(String message)
            {
                messagearea.append(message);
            }
        });
        tcpserver.start();
    }

    // METHODE POUR LIRE UN FICHIER AUDIO
    public void playMusic()
    {
        System.out.println("lecture de son");
        try 
        {
            Sound sound = new Sound("C:/Documents and Settings/cngo/Bureau/Stage-Save/TCPIP_AndroidJava/TCPIP_V6_Sound/OpeningSuite.mp3");
            System.out.println("playing : " + sound.isPlaying());
            sound.play();
            System.out.println("playing : " + sound.isPlaying());
        } 
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    // STOP LA MUSIQUE
    public void stopMusic()
    {
        System.out.println("arret de la musique");
        try 
        {
            sound.stop();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

**Here is my Sound.class :**

```
public class Sound 
{           
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private AdvancedPlayer player = null;

    public Sound(String path) throws Exception 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream)new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        player = new AdvancedPlayer(in);
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() 
    {
        return isPlaying;
    }   

    public void play() throws Exception
    {
        if (player != null) 
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            player.play();
        }
    }

    public Sound(String path,PlaybackListener listener) throws Exception 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream)new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        player = new AdvancedPlayer(in);
        player.setPlayBackListener(listener);
    }

    public void play(int begin,int end) throws Exception 
    {
        if (player != null) 
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            player.play(begin,end);
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception 
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.stop();
            isPlaying = false;

        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks to you in advance for your help.

Comment: Too much code, answering with my eyes closed: you are reading the file on the Event Dispatch Thread, thus freezing the entire GUI. Use a SwingWorker to load the file.

Comment: it seems `sound.play()` is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Java Sound based `Clip`.  Example code can be seen on the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  It runs in a daemon `Thread`, so won't block the Event Dispatch Thread.

> ..if I understand, the Java Sound is only for sampled audio data ?

MP3 *is* sampled audio data!  Given it is MP3, you should read the *entire* Java Sound info. page, which clearly explains how to provide support for MP3 in JSE.

> I need something light, really minimalist for my application, which allow me to read big audio files and/or an audio stream.

OK. If it is big you will need a [`BigClip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470886/418556).  Either that or a `SwingWorker` as suggested in other comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndrewThompson. But, if I understand, the Java Sound is only for sampled audio data ? I need something light, really minimalist for my application, which allow me to read big audio files and/or an audio stream.