# Problems with BigClip

Tags: java, url, audio, nullpointerexception, malformedurlexception

I have been trying to play music in my app. I've been using the example BigClip code:

```
try {
        url = new URL(Sounds.class.getResourceAsStream("title1.wav").toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BigClip clip = new BigClip();
        AudioInputStream ais = null;
        try {
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            clip.open(ais);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clip.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BigClip.start()");
        clip.loop(4);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BigClip.loop(4)");
        clip.setFastForward(true);
        clip.loop(8);
        // the looping/FF combo. reveals a bug..
        // there is a slight 'click' in the sound that should not be audible
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Are you on speed?");
}
```

When I only use `title1.wav`, I get this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: java.io.BufferedInputStream
```

When I add the protocol `file://`, I get a `NullPointerException`, although I can't see what could be causing that.

Am I using the wrong protocol, or have I done something else wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is in the same package ("directory") as the Sounds class, use

```
url = Sounds.class.getResource("title1.wav");
```

because

```
new URL(Sounds.class.getResourceAsStream("title1.wav").toString())
```

is just bound not to work. You are calling `toString` on an instance of InputStream.

The NPE probably happens because `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` fails due to bad URL path so `ais` is null and `BigClip` throws NPE from `open`.

Comment: Thank you, it works well now! Is there a reason why BigClip will cause the audio to start, stop, play the start again, keep going, and glitching?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with BigClip. If you mean the one by @AndrewThompson [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9470886/2891664) you might ask a new question about it and get his attention. (Post a comment to one of his answers with a link or ping him like I just did.) Though could be it is answerable by someone else.