# Java detecting an audio file (mp3)

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound, ogg

I have this code that reads an mp3 file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

    public class Sound {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            File sampleFile = new File("test.mp3");
            try {
                AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(sampleFile);
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that it is returning file not supported exception, the file here is an mp3 file. Java doesn't support mp3 files? if so what are others to validate an audio file?(like ogg, wav)

Comment: Only [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFileFormat.Type.html) are supported, not mp3.

Comment: @Esailija is there anyway to check if it is an mp3 file?

Comment: See also the **Service Provider Interface** & **MP3 decoding support** sections of the [Java Sound Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Comment: [Please take a look at this topic.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-audio-file-in-java-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) library. It can detect type of a file by its content and extract file metadata. It [supports](http://tika.apache.org/1.2/formats.html#Audio_formats) mp3 format.

Here is an [example](http://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/file-type-detection-with-apache-tika/) of file type detection with Apache Tika.

Comment: does it support other audio types besides mp3?

Comment: I can't seem to see code examples for Apache Tika Library, How would I detect the type of the file?

Comment: Okay, great it is working but how does Apache Tika, detects the file type? is it by its file extension or it decodes the file? because I'll be uploading the file from a file server, where I want a streamable file(audio clip

Comment: @kyelJmD Apache Tika detects file format by its content, not by its extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) library so that java audio api could recognize and decode mp3 files.

Comment: does it also support other audio media types?

Comment: @KyelJmD: the word `MP3` in the name suggests that no, it's for mp3 only.