# How to detect if file is mp3 using Apache tika TypeDetector?

Tags: java, apache-tika

How with apache tika can I detect if file is mp3?
I am not looking for just file extension based detection.

I am using:

```
typeTika = new Tika(new TypeDetector());
```

but when I try detect a type answer is always:

```
     application/octet stream
```

(whatever I send: mp3, image etc it's always application/octet stream)

What can I do to determine if file is mp3 or not?

This question is not a duplicate.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209644/java-detecting-an-audio-file-mp3) someone use Tika with file extension detection.
This is not enough for me.
I need to know if file is mp3 or not based on file type and not on a file name. I can't find any info in documentation how to do this.

TypeDetector always return application/octet stream for all files types so I want to know how to use it to get info if file is mp3 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [Apache Tika examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/):

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.mp3");

Tika tika = new Tika();
String type = tika.detect(file);
System.out.println(file + " : " + type);
```

That will detect on both the file contents and the file name. For an MP3 file, you'll get back `audio/mpeg`

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) can detect the `MIME Type` of each file. These days it's very common to use `Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions` file type designators (**MIME**), and each file format has got its own MIME. In the following some of them are mentioned: (For more visit [iana.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) or [fileformats.archiveteam.org](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/File_Formats))

- .mp3  --> `audio/mpeg`
- .mp4  --> `video/mp4`
- .flac --> `audio/x-flac` or `audio/flac`
- .png  --> `image/png`
- .jpg  --> `image/jpeg`
- .pdf  --> `application/pdf`
- .jar  --> `application/java-archive`

To use Tika in your project add the following maven dependency to your pom file:

```
<!-- Apache Tika: detects and extracts metadata and text from a variety of files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then use the mentioned code to detect your file's MIME type.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/music.mp3");
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mimeType = tika.detect(file);
System.out.println(mimeType); // Prints the MIME type of the file
```