# Adding music to JAVA simplest way

Tags: java

What is the simples way to add music to my JFrame ? I've tried this :

```
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File( "song.mp3") );
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread 
            // from terminating at the end of the main()
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
        }
    });
```

But it give me some sintax errors.

Comment: Java Audio won't play `mp3` files without additional plugins

Comment: What are the syntax error messages? Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: "It gives me some errors" - then you need to fix them.

Comment: (If nobody knows what the errors actually *are*, then how can they possibly know *how* to fix them?)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be 100% sure, but it would appear that you are ignoring, but you appear to be ignoring the exceptions thrown be various classes/methods, as the rest of the code seems to work okay...

```
try {
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("song.mp3"));
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread 
            // from terminating at the end of the main()
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
        }
    });
} catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, the other problem is, by default, Java Audio won't play MP3 files.  You can add support by including the `mp3plugin.jar` from the Java Media Framework, check out [Playing MP3 using Java Sound API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-mp3-using-java-sound-api) for more details

Another option is to use the `MP3SPI` supplied by [JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html), but they also have there own audio API, [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) which has worked well for me in the past

Comment: I am getting syntax error on the line at top of try block : Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token