# How can I read local .wav file into sound and play it in java

Tags: java, io

I wish to program a clock with alarm
How can I read the wav file (sound of alarm)into java and play it when the time is up.  I can read it from internet with this.

How can I read it from local directory 
E:\e-project\src\timer

Here is what I read from website, and it works.
I wish to read from local

```
TimerBell =JApplet.newAudioClip(new URL("http://web/~bl348/timer_bell.wav"));
```

Comment: Sorry, the answer in the previous link doesn't seem to be correct. [Try this.](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound)

Comment: Also demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886549/audio-file-plays-in-eclipse-ide-but-not-as-jar-file/29886855#29886855), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310900/adding-music-to-java-simplest-way/28310961#28310961) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836255/playing-multiple-sound-clips-using-clip-objects/29836764#29836764)