# How do I play an mp3 file for both an application and applet?

Tags: java, swing, audio, applet

I working on a program that both plays a sound when you click a button in an applet and in an application but I keep receiving an error while in the application portion of the program.

This is the error I get: sample.mp3 (The system cannot find the file specified)
but I clearly have it in my project.

```
public class project extends JApplet {

public void init() {
    add(new AppletOrApplicationMainComponent());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new AppletOrApplicationMainComponent());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class AppletOrApplicationMainComponent extends JPanel {

public AppletOrApplicationMainComponent() {

    super(new BorderLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Play");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Play();
        }
    });
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private void Play(){

    try{

        File file = new File("sample.mp3");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        Player player = new Player(bis);
        player.play();

    }catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Embed the mp3 within the application (allowing it to be included within the Jar file) and then simply use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to get a reference to it

Comment: Are you trying to run it in a jar or in your IDE?

Comment: *"keep receiving an error.."*  ..what error?  Always copy/paste error and exception output! `Player player = new Player(bis);` and what is a `Player`?  I don't see it in the Java 8 docs.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (include the imports).

Comment: Note: `File file = new File("sample.mp3");`  Application resources, applets and files mix like oil and water (very poorly).  Applet resources must be fetched by URL, as perhaps obtained via @MadProgrammer, first suggestion of `Class#getResource`.  When it comes to Java Sound 
(at least) I would avoid the 2nd form that produces an `InputStream` because Java Sound needs a repositionable input stream and the one returned from `getResourceAsStream` usually isn't.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's true. I did see solution for this, but I can't remember what it is :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Are you referring to.. *"Java Sound needs a repositionable input stream and the one returned from `getResourceAsStream` usually isn't."*?  If so, note that I deliberately did not explain for two reasons. 1) I have no evidence yet that the `Player` is based on Java Sound (there were hidden `sun` package applet sound classes that in some ways surpassed Java Sound - or at least they did). 2) The OP had actually implemented the fix in their file based code.  The fix is to wrap the input stream in a **buffered** input stream.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think `Player` is from JavaZoom JLayer MP3 library, at a guess ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I don't like guessing.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all that excitement, almost forgot to answer the question:

> How do I play an mp3 file for both an application and applet?

Firstly, using URL to access a resource is compatible with both applet and application.  The URL can be obtained from [`Class.getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).  For more details on using the method, see the [embedded resource info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

As to playing an MP3 for which we have an URL, see the MP3 decoding support section of the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  Basically it boils down to adding an MP3 SPI to the run-time class-path of the app.

Also note that the `Clip` convenience class mentioned in that page (and shown in the example) does not work with large files. From memory, it will hold at most 1 second of CD quality (stereophonic, 16 bit, 44.1 KHz) sound.  For larger files you might use an `AudioInputStream` directly, reading the bytes and feeding them back out to the sound API that plays them.  Either that or use [`BigClip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668510/418556), which caches the entire stream bytes in memory, much like `Clip`.