# Get audio to play in JAR File

Tags: java, swing

I know this question has been asked many times and I've looked at many in hopes to figure out my problems, but it didn't really help much. I was given this class to use to play WAV files on my GUI and it works when retrieving local files. But it doesn't work in a JAR file. I know this is because the music class only works for retrieving local files, so I need help changing the code to retrieve music files from the JAR.

Here's the SoundPlayer class:

```
package extra;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import org.pscode.xui.sound.bigclip.BigClip;

/**
 * A class to play audio clips. Caches previously-played clips,
 * allowing fast re-playback of previously played sounds.
 * 
 * @author Anon
 * @version 1.51
 */

public class SoundPlayer {

/** A cache of previously-played audio clips. */
private final Map<String, Clip> myClips = new HashMap<String, Clip>();

/**
 * Plays the audio file with the given file name.
 * This method returns instantly, without waiting for the clip to finish playing.
 * 
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to play.
 * @return a Clip object representing the sound played.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
public Clip play(final String theFilename) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return loop(theFilename, 1);
}

/** 
 * Plays the clip with the given file name in a continuous loop.
 * The clip keeps looping until it is later stopped by calling the 
 * stop() method. This function returns instantly
 *    
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to play.
 * @return a Clip object representing the sound played.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
public Clip loop(final String theFilename) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return loop(theFilename, Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

/** 
 * Plays the clip with the given file name in a loop.
 * The clip loops until it has played the specified number of times,
 * or until it is later stopped by calling the stop() method.
 * This function returns instantly, without waiting for the clip to finish looping.
 *
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to play.
 * @param theNumberOfTimes The number of times to loop the clip.
 * @return a Clip object representing the sound played.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
public Clip loop(final String theFilename, final int theNumberOfTimes) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException {

    final Clip clip = getClip(theFilename);

    if (clip != null) {
        clip.loop(theNumberOfTimes);
    }

    return clip;
}

/**
 * Pauses the clip with the given file name.
 * If the clip is later played, it will resume from where it was paused.
 * Calling this method does not resume a thread that is 
 * suspended on a playAndWait() or a loopAndWait().
 * 
 * If stop() is called on a paused clip, it will reset to the
 * beginning of the clip for the next play.
 * 
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to pause.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from
 * or playing the sound file.
 */
public void pause(final String theFilename) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final Clip clip = getClip(theFilename);

    if (clip != null) {
        final int pos = clip.getFramePosition();
        clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(pos);
    }
}

/** 
 * Stops the clip with the specified filename
 * (and wakes up any threads waiting for it to finish playing).
 * 
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to stop.
 * @return a Clip object representing the sound stopped.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
public Clip stop(final String theFilename) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final Clip clip = getClip(theFilename);
    stopClip(clip);

    return clip;
}

/** 
 * Stops all currently playing sound clips
 * (and wakes up the threads waiting for them to finish playing).
 */
public void stopAll() {
    for (final Clip clip : myClips.values()) {
        stopClip(clip);
    }
}   

/** 
 * Preloads the clip at the given file name.
 * This means the clip will be available faster, when requested for playing the first time.
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to preload.
 * @return a Clip object representing the preloaded sound.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
public Clip preLoad(final String theFilename) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return getClip(theFilename);
}


/**
 * Returns a Clip object for a filename, either by creating
 * a new one or loading it from the cache.
 * 
 * @param theFilename The name of the file to load.
 * @return a Clip object, or null if one is not found.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if there is a problem reading from the sound file.
 */
private Clip getClip(final String theFilename) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    BigClip clip = null;
    AudioInputStream ais = null;

    if (myClips.containsKey(theFilename)) {
        clip = (BigClip) myClips.get(theFilename);
    } else {
        // read audio file from disk
        try {
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(theFilename));


            clip = new BigClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                /** 
                 * Responds to audio events generated by clips. 
                 * 
                 * @param theEvent The event generated.
                 */
                public void update(final LineEvent theEvent) {
                    if (theEvent.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        // clip is done playing
                        stopClip((Clip) theEvent.getSource());
                    }
                }
            });
            myClips.put(theFilename, clip);
        } catch (final UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Not a valid supported audio file: \"" + theFilename + "\"", uafe);
        } catch (final LineUnavailableException lue) {
            lue.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Line is not available to play sound \"" + theFilename + " \"", lue);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("I/O error while reading file: \"" + theFilename + "\" ", ioe);
        }
    }

    return clip;
}

/**
 * Stops the playing of the specified clip.
 * 
 * @param theClip The clip.
 */
private void stopClip(final Clip theClip) {
    if (theClip != null) {
        synchronized (theClip) {
            theClip.stop();
            theClip.setFramePosition(0);
            theClip.notifyAll();  // awaken threads waiting for this Clip
        }
    }
}
}

// end of class SoundPlayer
```

In the getClip() method, I think that's where there needs to be a change since that's where the AudioInputStream is grabbing local files. I'm just not sure how to change it though.

Comment: *"I know this question has been asked many times and I've looked at many in hopes to figure out my problems,"* Link to the top 5, and.. *"but it didn't really help much."* ..explain ***why*** that did not solve this exact same problem.  `import org.pscode.xui.sound.bigclip.BigClip;` Huh.. haven't seen that in a while. :) Why are you using [`BigClip`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5668510/418556) as opposed to the standard `Clip` from the Java Sound API?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I actually have no idea why BigClip is being used, my professor provided the class. However, it works perfectly in Eclipse, so it seems like it's an okay choice.

Comment: The reason I recognized `BigClip` is because *I wrote it*. (But for a very specific purpose - i.e. large clips.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in a jar file can't actually be retrieved as a file. Instead, you need to use the `Class` object (usually the `this` variable)'s [`.getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) to retrieve a `URL` or [`.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to retrieve an `InputStream` for it.

You can then pass either of these into one of `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`'s overloads as it has [one for `InputStream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) and [one for `URL`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.net.URL-).

Comment: I just noticed that what you provided is what I tried previously and it didn't work. I forgot to include that in my post. It looks like this: `ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().
                                                      getResourceAsStream("/" + theFilename));`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("path/inside/of/jar")`.

**If the goal is to simply play sound:**

Try [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound). I recently used this in a project I'm working on, and it's mindblowingly easy to use. Make sure you use either `.wav` or `.ogg` files though, you can use http://media.io/ to convert to both of those.

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(..` Resources included in our Jars are **not** system resources. Instead use `this.getClass().getResource(..`.

Comment: Actually, I was able to get it working using `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()`.

Comment: *"Actually, I was able to get it working.."* I'm glad you were able to see it working on one machine/environment using `getSystemResource`. The problem is that it might not work on the next machine/environment. Don't mistake a single positive result for the correct way of going about a task.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this wasn't a cross-platform thing. I have however tried this both on Linux and on Windows, and they have worked. The nice thing about this is that it doesn't need to be used in a static context.